# SOAP xml response received but not populating response object

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap

I added a "Service Reference" to a vendor's Java based web service which i have no control over.

I have this simple client code:

```
   Client myClient = new Client();
   CapabilitiesType response = client.GetCapabilities(new GetCapabilitiesType1());
   myClient.Close();
   litCapabilities.Text = response.version;
```

Which generates the following SOAP evelope:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header></s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<GetCapabilities xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2"></GetCapabilities>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

So far so good, the above i got from Trace Viewer. Using both SoapUI and Trace Viewer, i can verify that i'm getting the correct response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header></SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<wrs:Capabilities xmlns:wrs="http://www.opengis.net/cat/wrs/1.0" xmlns:csw="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengeospatial.net/ows" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.0.0">
<ows:ServiceIdentification>
<ows:Title>EarthObservation ebRIM Catalogue</ows:Title>
<ows:Abstract>
        A web-based catalogue service that implements the CSW-ebRIM profile of the OGC Catalogue 2.0 specification, and the EO Extension Package
    </ows:Abstract>
<ows:Keywords>
<ows:Keyword>registry</ows:Keyword>
<ows:Keyword>catalogue</ows:Keyword>
<ows:Keyword>ebRIM</ows:Keyword>
<ows:Keyword>earth observation</ows:Keyword>
</ows:Keywords>
<ows:ServiceType>urn:ogc:service:catalogue:csw-ebrim</ows:ServiceType>
<ows:ServiceTypeVersion>2.0.2</ows:ServiceTypeVersion>
<ows:Fees>NONE</ows:Fees>
</ows:ServiceIdentification>
<ows:OperationsMetadata>
<ows:Operation name="GetCapabilities">
<ows:DCP>
<ows:HTTP>
<ows:Post xlink:href="http://999.999.999.999:8080/hma/ws/" xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></ows:Post>
</ows:HTTP>
</ows:DCP>
<ows:Parameter name="sections">
<ows:Value>ServiceIdentification</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>ServiceProvider</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>OperationsMetadata</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>Filter_Capabilities</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>ServiceProperties</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="AcceptVersions">
<ows:Value>2.0.2</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="AcceptFormats">
<ows:Value>application/xml</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
</ows:Operation>
<ows:Operation name="GetRecords">
<ows:DCP>
<ows:HTTP>
<ows:Post xlink:href="http://999.999.999.999:8080/hma/ws/"></ows:Post>
</ows:HTTP>
</ows:DCP>
<ows:Parameter name="resultType">
<ows:Value>hits</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>results</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="outputFormat">
<ows:Value>application/xml</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="outputSchema">
<ows:Value>urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="startPosition">
<ows:DefaultValue>1</ows:DefaultValue>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="maxRecords">
<ows:DefaultValue>10</ows:DefaultValue>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="TypeNames">
<ows:Value>rim:RegistryObject</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>rim:Association</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>rim:Classification</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>rim:ClassificationNode</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>rim:ClassificationScheme</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>urn:x-ogc:specification:csw-ebrim:ObjectType:EO:EOProduct</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>urn:x-ogc:specification:csw-ebrim:ObjectType:EO:EOAcquisitionPlatform</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>urn:x-ogc:specification:csw-ebrim:ObjectType:EO:EOBrowseInformation</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>urn:x-ogc:specification:csw-ebrim:ObjectType:EO:EOArchivingInformation</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="ElementName"></ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="ElementSetName">
<ows:Value>brief</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>summary</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>full</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="CONSTRAINTLANGUAGE">
<ows:Value>FILTER</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="DistributedSearch">
<ows:Value>FALSE</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="constraint"></ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="SortBy"></ows:Parameter>
</ows:Operation>
<ows:Operation name="GetRecordById">
<ows:DCP>
<ows:HTTP>
<ows:Post xlink:href="http://999.999.999.999:8080/hma/ws/"></ows:Post>
</ows:HTTP>
</ows:DCP>
<ows:Parameter name="Id">
<ows:Value></ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="outputFormat">
<ows:Value>application/xml</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="outputSchema">
<ows:Value>urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="ElementSetName">
<ows:Value>brief</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>summary</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>full</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
</ows:Operation>
<ows:Operation name="DescribeRecord">
<ows:DCP>
<ows:HTTP>
<ows:Post xlink:href="http://999.999.999.999:8080/hma/ws/"></ows:Post>
</ows:HTTP>
</ows:DCP>
<ows:Parameter name="TypeNames">
<ows:Value>rim:RegistryObject</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>rim:Association</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>rim:Classification</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>rim:ClassificationNode</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>rim:ClassificationScheme</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>urn:x-ogc:specification:csw-ebrim:ObjectType:EO:EOProduct</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>urn:x-ogc:specification:csw-ebrim:ObjectType:EO:EOAcquisitionPlatform</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>urn:x-ogc:specification:csw-ebrim:ObjectType:EO:EOBrowseInformation</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>urn:x-ogc:specification:csw-ebrim:ObjectType:EO:EOArchivingInformation</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="outputFormat">
<ows:Value>application/xml</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="schemaLanguage">
<ows:Value>http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
</ows:Operation>
<ows:Parameter name="service">
<ows:Value>CSW</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="version">
<ows:Value>2.0.2</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:ExtendedCapabilities xmlns:rim="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0">
<rim:Slot name="urn:ogc:def:ebRIM-Slot:OGC-06-131:parentIdentifier " slotType="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:DataType:String">
<rim:ValueList>
<rim:Value>urn:ogc:def:EOP:xxx-GSI:RSAT2_SEGMENTS</rim:Value>
</rim:ValueList>
</rim:Slot>
</ows:ExtendedCapabilities>
</ows:OperationsMetadata>
<ogc:Filter_Capabilities xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
<ogc:Spatial_Capabilities>
<ogc:GeometryOperands>
<ogc:GeometryOperand>gml:Envelope</ogc:GeometryOperand>
<ogc:GeometryOperand>gml:Point</ogc:GeometryOperand>
<ogc:GeometryOperand>gml:LineString</ogc:GeometryOperand>
<ogc:GeometryOperand>gml:Polygon</ogc:GeometryOperand>
</ogc:GeometryOperands>
<ogc:SpatialOperators>
<ogc:SpatialOperator name="BBOX"></ogc:SpatialOperator>
<ogc:SpatialOperator name="Overlaps"></ogc:SpatialOperator>
</ogc:SpatialOperators>
</ogc:Spatial_Capabilities>
<ogc:Scalar_Capabilities>
<ogc:LogicalOperators></ogc:LogicalOperators>
<ogc:ComparisonOperators>
<ogc:ComparisonOperator>LessThan</ogc:ComparisonOperator>
<ogc:ComparisonOperator>GreaterThan</ogc:ComparisonOperator>
<ogc:ComparisonOperator>LessThanEqualTo</ogc:ComparisonOperator>
<ogc:ComparisonOperator>GreaterThanEqualTo</ogc:ComparisonOperator>
<ogc:ComparisonOperator>EqualTo</ogc:ComparisonOperator>
<ogc:ComparisonOperator>NotEqualTo</ogc:ComparisonOperator>
</ogc:ComparisonOperators>
<ogc:ArithmeticOperators>
<ogc:SimpleArithmetic></ogc:SimpleArithmetic>
</ogc:ArithmeticOperators>
</ogc:Scalar_Capabilities>
</ogc:Filter_Capabilities>
<wrs:ServiceProperties>
<wrs:property name="http://www.opengis.net/cat/wrs/properties/extension-packages">
<wrs:value>urn:ogc:specification:csw-ebrim:ext-pkg:Basic</wrs:value>
<wrs:value>urn:x-ogc:specification:csw-ebrim:package:EOProducts</wrs:value>
</wrs:property>
<wrs:property name="http://www.opengis.net/cat/wrs/properties/query-languages">
<wrs:value>http://www.opengis.net/ogc</wrs:value>
<wrs:value>http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath</wrs:value>
</wrs:property>
<wrs:property name="http://www.opengis.net/cat/wrs/properties/mime-types">
<wrs:value>application/xml</wrs:value>
</wrs:property>
<wrs:property name="http://www.opengis.net/cat/wrs/properties/temporal-ref-systems">
<wrs:value>urn:ogc:def:trs:ISO-8601:2000</wrs:value>
</wrs:property>
<wrs:property name="http://www.opengis.net/cat/wrs/properties/spatial-ref-systems">
<wrs:value> urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.3:4326</wrs:value>
</wrs:property>
</wrs:ServiceProperties>
<wrs:WSDL-services xlink:href="http://999.999.999.999:8080/hma/ws/hma.wsdl" xlink:role="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/wsdl" xlink:title="HMA RSAT-2 Web Service End point" xlink:type="simple"></wrs:WSDL-services>
</wrs:Capabilities>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header></SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<wrs:Capabilities xmlns:wrs="http://www.opengis.net/cat/wrs/1.0" xmlns:csw="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengeospatial.net/ows" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.0.0">
<ows:ServiceIdentification>
<ows:Title>EarthObservation ebRIM Catalogue</ows:Title>
<ows:Abstract>
        A web-based catalogue service that implements the CSW-ebRIM profile of the OGC Catalogue 2.0 specification, and the EO Extension Package
    </ows:Abstract>
<ows:Keywords>
<ows:Keyword>registry</ows:Keyword>
<ows:Keyword>catalogue</ows:Keyword>
<ows:Keyword>ebRIM</ows:Keyword>
<ows:Keyword>earth observation</ows:Keyword>
</ows:Keywords>
<ows:ServiceType>urn:ogc:service:catalogue:csw-ebrim</ows:ServiceType>
<ows:ServiceTypeVersion>2.0.2</ows:ServiceTypeVersion>
<ows:Fees>NONE</ows:Fees>
</ows:ServiceIdentification>
<ows:OperationsMetadata>
<ows:Operation name="GetCapabilities">
<ows:DCP>
<ows:HTTP>
<ows:Post xlink:href="http://999.999.999.999:8080/hma/ws/" xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></ows:Post>
</ows:HTTP>
</ows:DCP>
<ows:Parameter name="sections">
<ows:Value>ServiceIdentification</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>ServiceProvider</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>OperationsMetadata</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>Filter_Capabilities</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>ServiceProperties</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="AcceptVersions">
<ows:Value>2.0.2</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="AcceptFormats">
<ows:Value>application/xml</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
</ows:Operation>
<ows:Operation name="GetRecords">
<ows:DCP>
<ows:HTTP>
<ows:Post xlink:href="http://999.999.999.999:8080/hma/ws/"></ows:Post>
</ows:HTTP>
</ows:DCP>
<ows:Parameter name="resultType">
<ows:Value>hits</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>results</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="outputFormat">
<ows:Value>application/xml</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="outputSchema">
<ows:Value>urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="startPosition">
<ows:DefaultValue>1</ows:DefaultValue>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="maxRecords">
<ows:DefaultValue>10</ows:DefaultValue>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="TypeNames">
<ows:Value>rim:RegistryObject</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>rim:Association</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>rim:Classification</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>rim:ClassificationNode</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>rim:ClassificationScheme</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>urn:x-ogc:specification:csw-ebrim:ObjectType:EO:EOProduct</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>urn:x-ogc:specification:csw-ebrim:ObjectType:EO:EOAcquisitionPlatform</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>urn:x-ogc:specification:csw-ebrim:ObjectType:EO:EOBrowseInformation</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>urn:x-ogc:specification:csw-ebrim:ObjectType:EO:EOArchivingInformation</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="ElementName"></ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="ElementSetName">
<ows:Value>brief</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>summary</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>full</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="CONSTRAINTLANGUAGE">
<ows:Value>FILTER</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="DistributedSearch">
<ows:Value>FALSE</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="constraint"></ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="SortBy"></ows:Parameter>
</ows:Operation>
<ows:Operation name="GetRecordById">
<ows:DCP>
<ows:HTTP>
<ows:Post xlink:href="http://999.999.999.999:8080/hma/ws/"></ows:Post>
</ows:HTTP>
</ows:DCP>
<ows:Parameter name="Id">
<ows:Value></ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="outputFormat">
<ows:Value>application/xml</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="outputSchema">
<ows:Value>urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="ElementSetName">
<ows:Value>brief</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>summary</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>full</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
</ows:Operation>
<ows:Operation name="DescribeRecord">
<ows:DCP>
<ows:HTTP>
<ows:Post xlink:href="http://999.999.999.999:8080/hma/ws/"></ows:Post>
</ows:HTTP>
</ows:DCP>
<ows:Parameter name="TypeNames">
<ows:Value>rim:RegistryObject</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>rim:Association</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>rim:Classification</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>rim:ClassificationNode</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>rim:ClassificationScheme</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>urn:x-ogc:specification:csw-ebrim:ObjectType:EO:EOProduct</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>urn:x-ogc:specification:csw-ebrim:ObjectType:EO:EOAcquisitionPlatform</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>urn:x-ogc:specification:csw-ebrim:ObjectType:EO:EOBrowseInformation</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>urn:x-ogc:specification:csw-ebrim:ObjectType:EO:EOArchivingInformation</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="outputFormat">
<ows:Value>application/xml</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="schemaLanguage">
<ows:Value>http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
</ows:Operation>
<ows:Parameter name="service">
<ows:Value>CSW</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="version">
<ows:Value>2.0.2</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:ExtendedCapabilities xmlns:rim="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0">
<rim:Slot name="urn:ogc:def:ebRIM-Slot:OGC-06-131:parentIdentifier " slotType="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:DataType:String">
<rim:ValueList>
<rim:Value>urn:ogc:def:EOP:xxx-GSI:RSAT2_SEGMENTS</rim:Value>
</rim:ValueList>
</rim:Slot>
</ows:ExtendedCapabilities>
</ows:OperationsMetadata>
<ogc:Filter_Capabilities xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
<ogc:Spatial_Capabilities>
<ogc:GeometryOperands>
<ogc:GeometryOperand>gml:Envelope</ogc:GeometryOperand>
<ogc:GeometryOperand>gml:Point</ogc:GeometryOperand>
<ogc:GeometryOperand>gml:LineString</ogc:GeometryOperand>
<ogc:GeometryOperand>gml:Polygon</ogc:GeometryOperand>
</ogc:GeometryOperands>
<ogc:SpatialOperators>
<ogc:SpatialOperator name="BBOX"></ogc:SpatialOperator>
<ogc:SpatialOperator name="Overlaps"></ogc:SpatialOperator>
</ogc:SpatialOperators>
</ogc:Spatial_Capabilities>
<ogc:Scalar_Capabilities>
<ogc:LogicalOperators></ogc:LogicalOperators>
<ogc:ComparisonOperators>
<ogc:ComparisonOperator>LessThan</ogc:ComparisonOperator>
<ogc:ComparisonOperator>GreaterThan</ogc:ComparisonOperator>
<ogc:ComparisonOperator>LessThanEqualTo</ogc:ComparisonOperator>
<ogc:ComparisonOperator>GreaterThanEqualTo</ogc:ComparisonOperator>
<ogc:ComparisonOperator>EqualTo</ogc:ComparisonOperator>
<ogc:ComparisonOperator>NotEqualTo</ogc:ComparisonOperator>
</ogc:ComparisonOperators>
<ogc:ArithmeticOperators>
<ogc:SimpleArithmetic></ogc:SimpleArithmetic>
</ogc:ArithmeticOperators>
</ogc:Scalar_Capabilities>
</ogc:Filter_Capabilities>
<wrs:ServiceProperties>
<wrs:property name="http://www.opengis.net/cat/wrs/properties/extension-packages">
<wrs:value>urn:ogc:specification:csw-ebrim:ext-pkg:Basic</wrs:value>
<wrs:value>urn:x-ogc:specification:csw-ebrim:package:EOProducts</wrs:value>
</wrs:property>
<wrs:property name="http://www.opengis.net/cat/wrs/properties/query-languages">
<wrs:value>http://www.opengis.net/ogc</wrs:value>
<wrs:value>http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath</wrs:value>
</wrs:property>
<wrs:property name="http://www.opengis.net/cat/wrs/properties/mime-types">
<wrs:value>application/xml</wrs:value>
</wrs:property>
<wrs:property name="http://www.opengis.net/cat/wrs/properties/temporal-ref-systems">
<wrs:value>urn:ogc:def:trs:ISO-8601:2000</wrs:value>
</wrs:property>
<wrs:property name="http://www.opengis.net/cat/wrs/properties/spatial-ref-systems">
<wrs:value> urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.3:4326</wrs:value>
</wrs:property>
</wrs:ServiceProperties>
<wrs:WSDL-services xlink:href="http://999.999.999.999:8080/hma/ws/hma.wsdl" xlink:role="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/wsdl" xlink:title="HMA RSAT-2 Web Service End point" xlink:type="simple"></wrs:WSDL-services>
</wrs:Capabilities>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But somehow this data is not making it's way back to my client code. Most properties within the response object are NULL.
[image]

Based on the SOAP response, The one property of response object that is not NULL is wrong (response.version) it should be "2.0.2" and not "1.0.0"

**Anyone know what i'm missing, or what could be wrong here?**

**Or what might help me troubleshoot this?**

Comment: You're not actually using anything in the WCF, at least according to your post.

Comment: @Mike: I thought "Add Service Reference" was using WCF. And "Add Web Reference" was using web services.

Comment: WCF is used for *hosting* services, and isn't restricted to just (web) services. That said, you could still end up connecting to a .NET WS that isn't built with WCF (it might be older, or just home-grown).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943180/c-response-object-contains-null-when-calling-java-web-service

Comment: Could you please find the generated code for CapabilitiesType and paste it here (or some part of it). It might be helpful to resolve this problem. Also, you say that version should be "2.0.2", however if you look at the response you've got you'll see that the version attribute indeed is "1.0.0" so that seems to be correct, right?

Comment: Yes Marten, you are correct about the "1.0.0". I've pasted the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to figure out my problem: There was a namespace mismatch.

The body of my request soap envelope contained:

```
<csw:GetCapabilities 
xmlns:csw="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2" 
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" 
xmlns:sch="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron" 
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" 
xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
```

In the response i was getting (top relevant characters only):

```
<wrs:Capabilities xmlns:wrs="http://www.opengis.net/cat/wrs/1.0" xmlns:csw="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengeospatial.net/ows" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.0.0">
```

**Notice how the OWS schema namespace in the REQUEST is pointing to http://www.opengis.net/ows**

**While the response is pointing to http://www.opengeospatial.net/ows**

Both namespaces have to be the same for .NET to deserialize the data. So you could just have the response respond the correct namespace. In my case, since i had no control over the Java Web Service, **i had to modify the auto-generated proxy class and replace all instances of “xmlns:ows=http://www.opengis.net/ows” for “xmlns:ows=http://www.opengeospatial.net/ows”**

Comment: For more details, on how to figure out the correct namespace which is required visit http://stackoverflow.com/a/31469374/1696326

Comment: Thank you @capdragon. Surely steered me in right direction to fix my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you might try to generate a client proxy using [SvcUtil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) instead of using a service reference. I am unaware as to whether they would generate the same client code, but you might as well try it anyway.

```
svcutil /target:code http://www.xyz.com/webService.wsdl /out:XYZWebServzice.cs
```

Comment: I tried it but i can't get it to successfully create any code. Since it won't follow and download all the includes, i can't determine what xsd files from the schema to include in the command line. and the command is getting HUGE (too long to post) ie: svcutil wisdel.wsdl D:\temp\OGCSchemas\csw\2.0.2\profiles\ebrim\1.0\csw-ebrim.xsd xsd2.xsd xsd3.xsd xsd4.xsd ... xsd34.xsd

Comment: You don't have to specify all the xsd's if you post a remote URL for the WSDL. `Svcutil follows imports and includes when you specify a remote URL for metadata. However, if you want to process metadata files on the local file system, you must specify all files in this argument.`

Comment: OMG Mike i needed you months ago! I did not know it followed it if you placed it on ISS or in a URL form! That is awesome! +1 on all your comments for that VERY useful piece of information. I should have been doing it like this a LONG time ago.

Comment: Same results though :/ Still, much appreciated answer and comment.